# Leer XML con SAX y crear otro con DOM

Tags: java, xml, dom, sax

Tengo que hacer un ejercicio en que tengo que leer un archivo xml con SAX y después a partir de este crear otro con DOM. La parte de Sax creo que la tengo bien, tengo creada la clase UserHandler extendida a DefaultHandler con sus métodos y hasta ahí todo bien, lo leeo tal como le digo. Lo que no sé como hacer es la segunda parte, en el main, a parte de tener el File para leer el archivo con sax, tengo instanciado el documento Dom y creado la raiz y varios elementos, pero lo que no sé es como pasar la información del xml leído por el sax a estos elementos.

Esta es la clase UserHander que uso para leer el xml:

class UserHandler extends DefaultHandler {

```
boolean nombre = false;
boolean apellidos = false;
boolean aCodigo = false;
boolean nota = false;



@Override  
   public void startDocument() throws SAXException {  
      System.out.println("\nPrincipio del documento...");  
   }  

@Override  
   public void endDocument() throws SAXException {  
      System.out.println("\nFin del documento...");  
   }      
  
@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("estudiante")) {
        String dni = attributes.getValue("DNI");
        System.out.println("Estudiante Dni : " + dni);          
    } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("nombre")) {
        nombre = true;
    } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("apellidos")) {
        apellidos = true;
    } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("asignatura")) {
        String cod = attributes.getValue("CODIGO");
        System.out.println("Asignatura Codigo : " + cod);
        aCodigo = true;
    } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("nota")) {
        String eval = attributes.getValue("EVAL");
        System.out.println("Nota Evaluacion : " + eval);
        nota = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {

    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("student")) {
        System.out.println("End Element :" + qName);
    }
}

@Override
public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {

    if (nombre) {
        System.out.println("Nombre: " + new String(ch, start, length));
        nombre = false;
    } else if (apellidos) {
        System.out.println("Apellidos: " + new String(ch, start, length));
        apellidos = false;      
    } else if (nota) {
        System.out.println("Nota: " + new String(ch, start, length));
        nota = false;
    }

}
```

Y este el main:

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, TransformerException {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

```
    try {
        File inputFile = new File("estudiantes.xml");
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
        UserHandler userhandler = new UserHandler();
        saxParser.parse(inputFile, userhandler);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    
    Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
    Element rootElement = doc.createElement("lista_alumnos");
    doc.appendChild(rootElement);
    
    Element estudiante = doc.createElement("estudiante");
    rootElement.appendChild(estudiante);
    
    //Hasta aquí todo bien, lo que no sé es cómo pasar la información del SAX al DOM
    Attr attr = doc.createAttribute("dni");
    attr.setValue("?dni?");
    estudiante.setAttributeNode(attr);
    
    Element nombre = doc.createElement("nombre");
    nombre.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("fgfgf"));
    estudiante.appendChild(nombre);     
    
    Element apellidos = doc.createElement("apellidos");
    apellidos.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("?apellido?"));
    estudiante.appendChild(apellidos);
    
    Element asignatura = doc.createElement("asignatura");       
    estudiante.appendChild(asignatura);     
    
    Attr attr2 = doc.createAttribute("codigo");
    attr2.setValue("?codigo?");
    asignatura.setAttributeNode(attr2);
    
    Element nota = doc.createElement("nota");
    nota.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("?nota?"));
    asignatura.appendChild(nota);
    
    Attr attr3 = doc.createAttribute("eval");
    attr3.setValue("?eval?");
    nota.setAttributeNode(attr3);       
    
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("alumnos.xml"));        

    transformer.transform(source, result);

    System.out.println("File saved!");
}
```

Comment: Hola MasQ, bienvenido a SO en Español. Para obtener respuestas y que se entienda mejor tu pregunta, debes añadir el código que estás intentando. Por favor, lee [cómo elaborar una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Gracias Brahim por la aclaración. aunque tampoco sé si ahora está bien formulada la pregunta.